# ggplot2 footnote

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

What is the best way to add a footnote to the bottom of a plot created with ggplot2?  I've tried using a combination of the logic noted [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-good-practice-%E2%80%93-adding-footnotes-to-graphics/) as well as the ggplot2 `annotate` function.

```
p + annotate("text",label="Footnote",
  x=unit(1,"npc") - unit(2, "mm"),y=unit(2, "mm"),
  just=c("right", "bottom"),gp=gpar(cex= 0.7, col=grey(.5)))
```

but I am getting the error

> Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : cannot coerce class c("unit.arithmetic", "unit") into a data.frame

Comment: This works if you view the plot in R but it doesn't look like it works with the     ggsave function.

Comment: Then open an appropriate graphics device instead of using `ggsave()`, e.g., `pdf("filename.pdf", width=10, height=6); print(p); grid.text(...); dev.off()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use something like that:

```
pdf("filename.pdf", width=10, height=6) # open an appropriate graphics device
print(p)
makeFootnote() # from webpage above (uses grid.text; ggplot2 is based on grid)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Yes, this is excellent.  Also, if you need ggplot2 to leave a little more margin for your footnote, try this:   p + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,2,1), "lines"))

Answer (score 38):

## `labs(caption = "my caption")` adds a footnote:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour = cyl)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(caption = "(Pauloo, et al. 2017)")
```

[image]

Comment: Can we make the caption left-aligned?

Comment: Try `+ theme(plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0))`. For a centered legend, use `just = 0.5`. By default, `hjust = 1`. `hjust` stands for "horizontal justification," and ranges from 0-1, left to right, so that 0 is all the way left, 1 is all the way right, and 0.5 is in the middle, and so on.