# Saving a graph with ggsave after using ggplot_build and ggplot_gtable

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

I am modifying a graph built with ggplot by altering the data produced by ggplot_build (for a reason similar to [Include space for missing factor level used in fill aesthetics in geom_boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367762/r-ggplot-empty-factor-level)). As far as I understand the help I found on this topic, I should be able to save the result by applying ggplot_gtable and arrangeGrob before calling ggsave on the results ([Saving grid.arrange() plot to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059099/saving-grid-arrange-plot-to-file)).

However I obtain an error "plot should be a ggplot2 plot", also with this simple reproductible example:

```
require('ggplot2')
require('gridExtra')
df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
                  f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("young","old")),
                  boxthis=rnorm(100))
g <- ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + geom_boxplot()
dd <- ggplot_build(g)

# Printing the graph works:
print(arrangeGrob(ggplot_gtable(dd)))

# Saving the graph doesn't:
ggsave('test.png',arrangeGrob(ggplot_gtable(dd)))
```

Can anybody explain why this does not work ? Is there a way to use ggsave after modifying the data by using ggplot_build() ?

(My version of the packages are gridExtra_0.9.1 and ggplot2_0.9.3.1)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it does not work because `ggsave` wants an object of class `ggplot`, while you're passing a grob. `arrangeGrob` will sometimes trick `ggsave` in pretending inheritance from `ggplot`, but only when at least one of the grobs belongs to this class; here, however, you're only passing a `gtable`.

Perhaps the easiest workaround is to clone ggsave and bypass the class check,

```
ggsave <- ggplot2::ggsave; body(ggsave) <- body(ggplot2::ggsave)[-2]
```

**Edit:** The dev version of ggplot2 no longer requires this hack*, as `ggsave` [now works with any grob](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/7387d39ad9a2121be393f2e0d9215d6e1bbc3b1a).

*PS: this hack works no longer, as arrangeGrob now returns a gtable, and its print method does not draw on a device.

Comment: Thanks. This, in combination with [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/20433318/2173340), fixed my problem of saving plots created by 'ggplot2' using 'gtable' with 'ggsave'.

Comment: @baptiste I tried your trick with the overwriting `ggsave` function but it is not working in my case. At the same time, `ggplot` is still `1.0.1` and the problem is not fixed yet. If I use your method, I create a pdf file using `ggsave('test.pdf', arrangeGrob(p1, p2))` but it is corrupted in a way. At the same time the `gtable` get printed in the console. So something is not properly working.

Comment: I just updated to gridExtra_2.0.0 and I have ggplot2_1.0.1  installed (which both seem to be the newest version on CRAN). As you state in your update `arrangeGrob` now returs a gtable, while `ggsave` still tests the class of the plot object. Do I have to install the development version of ggplot to save a plot done with arrangeGrob?

Comment: Yes, note that a ggplot2 update is meant to be released soon, last time I checked last month

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to plot the gtable object with grid.draw() and then use dev.copy() to transfer the plot to a file.

Remember to use also dev.off() just afterward.