# ggplot2: Adding a second x-Axis with labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for something similar. In my case, I do have 6 different labels on the x axis - let it be "January", "February", "June", "July" and "September", "October". As you can see, 2 months can always be grouped into one season: "Winter", "Summer" and "Autumn". I have six values (one for each month), let it be temperature. Now my x-Axis has 6 ticks and labels. I would, however, like to add a second axis with "Winter" appearing below "January" and "February" and so on.
Any idea on how that could work?

Here's my code so far:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(colour=group, y= temperature, x= month))
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(aes(shape=c("15", "15", "16", "16", "17", "17")),size = 1.5)+               
  geom_errorbar(limits2, width=0.1, size = 0.5) +                                        
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,5), name = "Temperature")+                                
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=0.4))+                                          
  scale_x_discrete(name = "MONTH", labels=c("January", "February", "June", "July", "September", "October"))+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.2))
p1
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is very an inelegant way to add texts below the main plot and the axis label. Since I don't have the original data, let me illustrate using the "mtcars" data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
(g0 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, colour=factor(am))) + geom_point(size=4) +
   theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3,1), "cm")))

Text1 <- textGrob("Spring")
Text2 <- textGrob("Summer")
Text3 <- textGrob("Fall")
(g1 <- g0 + annotation_custom(grob = Text1,  xmin = 3, xmax = 3, ymin = 5, ymax = 5) +
   annotation_custom(grob = Text2,  xmin = 4, xmax = 4, ymin = 5, ymax = 5) +
   annotation_custom(grob = Text3,  xmin = 5, xmax = 5, ymin = 5, ymax = 5))

gg_table <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gg_table$layout$clip[gg_table$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gg_table)
```

You can tweek the ymin and xmin values to move the texts around.

If you want to save the `gg_table` as a grob, you need to use `arrangeGrob()` and "clone ggsave and bypass the class check" (according to [the answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406991/saving-a-graph-with-ggsave-after-using-ggplot-build-and-ggplot-gtable)):

```
g <- arrangeGrob(gg_table)
ggsave <- ggplot2::ggsave
body(ggsave) <- body(ggplot2::ggsave)[-2]
ggsave(file="./figs/figure.png", g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that works perfectly! It is just that my ggsave function now does not combine the plot and the table...any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: For some reason, you need to use `arrangeGrob()` to assign the `gg_table` to a grob. See above.