# Add secondary X-axis with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, facet

Seems that this topic has not been covered this since the [ggplot2.2.2 update](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/09/30/ggplot2-2-2-0-coming-soon/) where old solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26917689/how-to-use-facets-with-a-dual-y-axis-ggplot?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776995/ggplot2-adding-a-second-x-axis-with-labels) no longer apply. Fortunately, the process is far simpler than before. One line of code and you have a secondary Y-axis ([as shown here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html)).

But I cannot get a secondary X-axis on my plots...

I am comparing a depth profile of metal concentrations along the sediment core. I would like to display carbon and phosphate concentrations as an `geom_area` behind the metal's concentration. The problem is that both carbon and phosphate concentrations are no on the same scale as the metal. Thus I need a second axis.

The theme is the following (taken from [this website](http://blarquez.com/author/admin/)):

```
theme_new <- theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor =  element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), strip.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=0, vjust=0), strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0), legend.position="none",panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45,hjust=1)) # Axis tick label angle
```

And this code gives me a second Y-axis even though I specify it under X-axis.

```
ggplot(MasterTable)+
  geom_line(aes(Depth,Conc.nM))+
  geom_area(aes(Depth,Conc.uM, fill=Variable))+
  scale_x_continuous("Depth (cm)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *100, name = "Carbon & Phosphate"))+
  scale_y_continuous("Metal concentration (nM)")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_new+
  theme(legend.position = "right")+
  facet_grid(. ~ Assay, scales = "free")
```

[image: ggplot2 figure]

Can anyone help me place the secondary axis on the top of the figure?

Thanks!!

dput of my MasterTable is the following:

structure(list(Depth = c(15L, 5L, 2L, -1L, -3L, -5L, -7L, -9L, 
-11L, -13L, -15L, -17L, -19L, -21L, -23L, -25L, -27L, -29L, -31L, 
15L, 5L, 2L, -1L, -3L, -5L, -7L, -9L, -11L, -13L, -15L, -17L, 
-19L, -21L, -23L, -25L, -27L, -29L, -31L), Conc.nM = c(24L, 24L, 
24L, 100L, 100L, 75L, 75L, 85L, 85L, 120L, 300L, 1000L, 200L, 
240L, 240L, 800L, 1100L, 1500L, 2300L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 50L, 200L, 
200L, 50L, 50L, 200L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 120L, 200L, 1500L, 2100L, 
2000L, 2000L), Assay = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Instrument 1", 
"Instrument 2"), class = "factor"), Conc.uM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 
10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Variable = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Carbon", "Phosphate"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Depth", 
"Conc.nM", "Assay", "Conc.uM", "Variable"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Brian's answer, and modifying the theme proposed above, I got the following figure.

[image: Sediment core]

As he suggested, you have to first modify your data manually using something like this:

```
MasterTable$Conc.uM <- MasterTable$Conc.uM *100
```

Then, in the code, adjust your axis with the same correction factor as the one used above. Here is the code to make the figure.

```
ggplot(MasterTable)+
  geom_line(aes(Depth,Conc.nM))+
  geom_area(aes(Depth,Conc.uM, fill=Variable), alpha=0.6)+                            #Area for second X-axis
  geom_area(aes(Depth,Conc.nM), alpha=0.95)+                                     
  geom_point(aes(Depth,Conc.uM), size=1, shape=16, alpha=0.3)+                        #Adding points for second X-axis
  geom_point(aes(Depth,Conc.nM), size=1, shape=16, alpha=0.8)+   
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours) + scale_colour_manual(values=colours) +      

  labs(title="Sediment core", color="",fill="")  +                                    #Place legend title in both color="" and fill=""

  scale_y_continuous("Metal concentration (nM)", 
                 sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . /100, name = "[Pi] (uM)                                             DOC (mg/L)"))+    
  scale_x_continuous("Depth (cm)", breaks=pretty_breaks(n=7))+

  coord_flip()+                                                                       #Required to make a proper depth profile 
  theme_new+                                                                          #Reference to custom theme
  facet_grid(. ~ Assay, scales = "free")                                              #Scales makes that the axis size can change
```

Now I just have one problem left to solve. I would like for the tick marks and labels to be under the facet. Seems more logical and less busy than having it at the top of the figure.

Comment: `+ theme(strip.placement = "outside")`

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
...
  scale_x_continuous("Depth (cm)", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *100, name = "Carbon & Phosphate"))+
  scale_y_continuous("Metal concentration (nM)") + 
  coord_flip() ...
```

Consider which primary axis you want "Carbon & Phosphate" to be parallel to. Also consider what "x-axis" and "y-axis" mean in the context of using `coord_flip`.

**TL;DR**: Just move your secondary axis into `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for this. good catch, it now displays the x-axis on top. But the data is not following this axis. It is still linked to the bottom x-axis. Is there a way to specify that I would like Conc.uM data to follow sec_axis?

Comment: The data are the data, they don't "follow" a particular axis. They should be pre-transformed to a common scale (e.g. multiply by 1000 to put your micromoles in nanomoles); then your second axis simply *relabels* them. Can't do much more to help without at least a subset of your data.

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I saw it as well. Here is my data file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9t1ppyfvm983try/LAS2016_Master-table8.csv?dl=0

Comment: Please put the output from `dput(MasterTable)` in the text of your question. Many SO users won't have access to dropbox (or your link may die eventually).

Comment: Thanks Brian, pre-adjusting them to the same scale worked! I will post the results for others shortly.