# Change facet labels for a ggplot created by ggfortify::autoplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I'm trying to change the facet labels for an `stl` decomposition plot like the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
p <- autoplot(stl(AirPassengers, s.window = 'periodic'), ts.colour = "black", ts.size = 0.2)
p
```

The plot originates from the [ggfortify package](http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/plot_tsstats).
I wish to change the facet labels to:

```
c("Original Data", "Seasonal component", "Trend component", "Remainder")
```

I've tried to get into the structure of a `ggplot` (a lot of `str`'ing), and found that the following stores these names:

```
str(p$layers[[1]]$data$variable)
# Factor w/ 4 levels "Data","seasonal",..: 1 1 1
```

However, when I change this factor in-place. I get four empty plots followed by the proper plots:

```
p$layers[[1]]$data$variable <- factor(p$layers[[1]]$data$variable,
                                      labels=c("Original series", "Seasonal Component", "Trend component", "Remainder"))
```

[image: Outcome when editing factor in-place]

How do I change the facet labels without getting these empty plots at the top?

Comment: You will have to dig into the attributes of `x$time.series` and I think `Data` is semi-hard coded (see for example https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/fea0b6f54ed814583d9a53f4815ecc65265f5d3c/R/base_fortify_ts.R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to change the relevant components of the plot object.

```
# generate plot data which can be rendered
g <- ggplot_build(p)

# inspect the object and find the relevant element to be changed
# str(g)

# perform desired changes
g$panel$layout$variable <- c("Original Data", "Seasonal component", "Trend component", "Remainder")

# build a grob and 'draw' it
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(g))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. I just had an issue with ggsave not liking the draw.table part. Loading gridExtra and modifying ggsave as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18407452/3191230 completely solved it. Thanks alot!