# Unable to save KM plot using ggsave in R

Tags: r

I am trying to save a KM plot using ggsave but my following code isn't saving the file on my Mac:

```
# Fit survival curves
require("survival")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
# Visualize
library("survminer")
p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung,
                surv.median.line = "hv", # Add medians survival
                pval = TRUE,             # Add p-value and tervals
                
                conf.int = TRUE,        # Add the 95% confidence band
                risk.table = TRUE,      # Add risk table
                tables.height = 0.2,
                tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
                palette = "jco",
                ggtheme = theme_bw()
)
print(p)

ggsave(filename = "Test.png",
       plot = print(p),
       path = "~/Desktop/",
       width = 8,
       height = 7,
       dpi =  300)
```

The code runs properly without any errors but and I can see the sample KM curve appear in R. However, no saved image file appears on my desktop. I would really appreciate any help with this request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggsave ggsurvplot with risk.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74887512/ggsave-ggsurvplot-with-risk-table)

Comment: If `risk.table = TRUE`,  do `png("Test.png"); print(p, newpage = FALSE); dev.off()` instead.

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I gave this a go but received the following error: `Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "c('ggsurvplot', 'ggsurv', 'list')" `

Answer (score 2):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/152) you could use the `ggexport` function of the `ggpubr` package to save the image like this (**Don't forget to change your path**):

```r
require("survival")
library("survminer")
fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung,
                surv.median.line = "hv", # Add medians survival
                pval = TRUE,             # Add p-value and tervals
                
                conf.int = TRUE,        # Add the 95% confidence band
                risk.table = TRUE,      # Add risk table
                tables.height = 0.2,
                tables.theme = theme_cleantable(),
                palette = "jco",
                ggtheme = theme_bw()
)

library(ggpubr)
ggexport(filename = "Test.png",
         plot = p, device = "png")
#> [1] "Test%03d.png"
#> file saved to Test%03d.png
```

Output:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to save this as a high resolution image by specifying the dpi?